# Keeping count of the number of times a text field has been dynamically added using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to dynamically add new text fields into my HTML form on the click of a link using JavaScript. On each click of the link, a new text field gets inserted into my form. Here's my code for implementing this event:

HTML

```
<a onclick = "addNewCeleb()">Add a Microceleb</a>
<div id = "celebrity"/>
```

JavaScript

```
function addNewCeleb()
        {
                var celeb = document.createElement("input");
                celeb.type = "text";
                celeb.name = "handle";
                celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
                celebrity.appendChild(celeb);
        }
```

Now, I want a way to keep a count of the number of times the link has been clicked, because I want to differentiate each text field by its name as follows:

```
celeb.name = "handle" + count
```

where `count` would be `1` the first time the link is clicked, so that its corresponding text field is named `handle1`. Similarly for other text fields as well; the text field added after the first one would be named `handle2` and so on.

How can I implement this in my current JavaScript code? I'd appreciate if someone could provide a non-JQuery solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try if this works for you

```
<a onclick = "addNewCeleb()">Add a Microceleb</a>
<div id = "celebrity"/>

    function addNewText()
                {
         var index=0;
         return  function(){ 
                        index += 1;
                        var celeb = document.createElement("input");
                        celeb.type = "text";
                        celeb.name = "handle" + index;
                        celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
                        celebrity.appendChild(celeb);
                      }
          }
    var addNewCeleb= new addNewText();
```

this will create a private scope for index variable and nobody can change it then it will become a private variable for addNewText and will not pollute global scope as well.

Answer (score 1):

Define a global counter and while call increment it

```
<script>
  function addNewCeleb(){
     var celeb = document.createElement("input");
     var container = document.getElementById('celebrity');
     var lastNode = container.childNodes[container.childNodes.length-1] ;
     var count = lastNode && lastNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'input' ? parseInt(lastNode.name.replace('handle',''))+1 : 1;
     celeb.type = "text";
     celeb.name = "handle"+count;
     celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
     container.appendChild(celeb);
  }
</script>

<body>
  <a onclick = "addNewCeleb()">Add a Microceleb</a>
  <div id = "celebrity"/>
</body>
```

Comment: That's ok to skip the hurdle, but it's a poor design choice.

Comment: @Amit Can you elaborate more on why it's a poor design choice?

Comment: I do agree, globals can be a tough bad thing always

Comment: See @Novice's answer. At least it makes sure the counter is incremented internally in the `addNewCeleb` function. It's part of that function's responsibility to do so

Comment: I like everyone posting globals. @ManasChaturvedi we will see if we can get a better design. One thing would be counting the children of the div#celebrity, I can guess thats a global as well

Comment: Why is defining and incrementing a global variable such a bad thing in JavaScript? I don't get it.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi - Read about encapsulation.

Comment: @Amit Well yes, makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi the problem with defining variable in global scope is that it will not be a private variable and any other function can have access to it and can change it which will give you undesirable result.
Also as  dynamic typing is possible in JavaScript if you by mistake create a variable with same name in the global scope it will override the previous value.

Comment: Ok great now we have code w/o a global reference, @Amit thanks buddy for the good call. Me I hate those globals... updated code   Hurrayyy

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest solution is to create a variable in the global scope and increment it every time you append a new text field like this

```
var index = 0;   
 function addNewCeleb()
            {
                    index += 1;
                    var celeb = document.createElement("input");
                    celeb.type = "text";
                    celeb.name = "handle" + index;
                    celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
                    celebrity.appendChild(celeb);
            }
```

Poluting the global scope is not a very good practice is javascript however but this is probably the easiest fix the alternative to this would be creating a closure.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your increment variable's scope contained would be better than using a global variable, I suggest something like:

```
var addNewCeleb = function() {
  var count = 0;

  return function() {
    count++;
    var celeb = document.createElement("input");
    celeb.type = "text";
    celeb.name = "handle"+count;
    celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
    document.getElementById('celebrity').appendChild(celeb);
  }
}();
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtfzhfxr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I see that most answers play with a global variable, I would say that this can be a decent use. However, here is a different approach using the HTML data- attribute

```
<script>
    function addNewCeleb(){
     var myLink= document.getElementById('myLink');
     var counter =Number(myLink.getAttribute('data-counter'));
     var celeb = document.createElement("input");
     counter+=1;   
     celeb.type = "text";
     celeb.name = "handle"+counter;
     celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
     celebrity.appendChild(celeb);
     myLink.setAttribute('data-counter',counter);
    }
</script>

<body>
  <a id="myLink" data-counter="0" onclick = "addNewCeleb()">Add a Microceleb</a>
  <div id = "celebrity"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class to the created element and count the number of elements that have that custom class.

the code would be

```
function addNewCeleb()
{

        var celeb = document.createElement("input");
        var celebrity = document.getElementById("celebrity");
        var count = document.querySelectorAll('.specific-class').length;
        celeb.type = "text";
        celeb.name = "handle" + count;
        celeb.class = "specific-class"
        celeb.placeholder = "Twitter handle";
        celebrity.appendChild(celeb);
}
```

Comment: Say tomorrow we have a removal function you never know what count should be , Say you have 3 divs now you click you have div4 now you remove 2nd div then click will create div4 again. Wrong